# Mounting Encrypted DMG through terminal

Tags: macos

I have to write a python script that opens a series of encrypted DMGs on Mac and I was following this tutorial
 [Tutorial](http://techanic.net/2012/10/14/programmatically_mounting_encrypted_disk_images_in_os_x.htm)

The basic command that I am using is the following, I tried it on terminal directly.

```
echo "Password" | hdiutil attach /path/DMG.dmg
```

What happens is that it asks for the password and echo is not working. I need a way to do all in code.

Comment: In general for cases like this you can use `expect` to feed input to another program (`hdiutil` in your case) as if it came from a user.

Comment: Have you tried `echo -n PASSWORD`?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198539

Answer (score 2):

You fogot the **-stdinpass** argument:

```
echo -n "Password" | hdiutil attach -stdinpass /path/DMG.dmg
```

Comment: You need to add `-n` as Mark Setchell pointed out. Otherwise there will be a newline at the end of echo's output and the password won't match.